# How to query by reference field in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two Mongo schemas:

User:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: String,
  country: ObjectId // Reference to schema Country
}
```

Country:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: String
}
```

I want to get all users who have the country name "VietNam".

What kind of query (only to the User schema) can I use for this case?

I want it to look like this SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM User
JOIN Country 
ON User.country = Country._id 
WHERE Country.name = 'VietNam'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below aggregation with mongodb **3.6** and above

```
db.country.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "name": "VietNam" } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Users.collection.name,
    "let": { "countryId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$country", "$$countryId" ] } } },
    ],
    "as": "users",
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$users" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$users" }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks. It's worked very well. But can I combine conditions as user.name = 'Anthony' and country.name = 'VietNam' ?

Comment: you can. pipeline can contain multiple condition.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike relational databases, this isn't something that Mongo is good at, and you should generally structure your schemas in a different way when you're using NoSQL. In this case, you could add a `countryName` field to the `user` collection (and perhaps an index on country) so that you can query `{countryName: "Vietnam"}`. (Instead of country-name, it'd likely make more sense to use the iso-2 country code)

If you do need to do a "join" you can use the [`$lookup` operator in the aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) -- just keep in mind that aggregations don't scale well and tend to be a little hard to write.

Comment: So when I update country name of countryId A. I have to find all User records have countryId are A and update all that records ?? It's ok for performance

Comment: How often do country names (or iso-2 country codes) change? Updating all user entities is a really expensive operation, but it's one that will only happen rarely (and can be avoided by having application-side code do the rename). Having an extra look-up with every query is going to end up being much more expensive.

Comment: But with records usually to be changed ?

Comment: In general, you'll want to denormalize your data in mongo & part of that work often involves making sure that multiple documents stay in sync. If records often change, using $lookup can let you return documents from different collections. How to structure your data & queries depends strongly on your use-case

Answer (score 1):

if you want to associate 2 or more collections you must define the reference object of the collection

my solution please check this https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 0):

Heres the code I generally use:

Models/users.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Countries = require("./countries");

const UsersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: Sting,
    country: Countries.schema
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Users", UsersSchema);
```

controllers/users.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Users = require("../models/users");

router.post("/register", async(req, res) => {
    try{
      const Me = await Users.create({name: req.body.name, country: req.body.country})
      /* If you make the request correctly on the frontend req.body.name is a 
         string and req.body.country is an object with one property, it's name */
      res.status(200).json({
          data: Me
      });
    }
    catch(err){
      res.status(400).json({message:err.message})
```

Since the subschema is an object you reference it as Me.country.name. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. But I want to keep 2 schema and User only store country Id, not country Object. Because country collection will be used to show list countries, should separate to 2 schema.
And main problem is I don't know how to query to user by country name

Comment: you would still have 2 collections of documents but if you want to call the user by the country you do `Users.findMany({ country: req.body.country})`. I guess I read your question wrong but [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-collection/) is a great reference to all things MongoDB.