# Filter query for fetching product based on categories in MERN application?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my `Product Schema`

```
const product = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    category:{
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: Category
    }
}
```

I want to return the product based on filters coming from the front end.
For example: Lets consider there are 2 categories `Summer` and `Winter`. When the user wants to filter product by `Summer` Category an api call would me made to `http://localhost:8000/api/products?category=summer`

Now my question is, how do I filter because from the frontend I am getting category name and there is ObjectId in Product Schema.
My attempt:
`Project.find({category:categoryName})`

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54642073/10787160

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you can try one of these queries:

First one is using pipeline into `$lookup` to match by `category` and `name` in one stage like this:

```
yourModel.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "category",
      "let": {
        "category": "$category",
        
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$id",
                    "$$category"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$name",
                    "Summer"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "categories"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "categories": {
        "$ne": []
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4mvwUmGw9G5)

Other way is using normal `$lookup` and then `$filter` the array returned by join.

```
yourModel.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "category",
      "localField": "category",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "as": "categories"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "categories": {
        "$ne": []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "categories": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$categories",
          "as": "c",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$c.name",
              "Summer"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O44UmViiB5t)

Note how both queries uses `$match: { categories: { $ne : []}}`, this is because if the lookup doesn't find any result it returns an empty array. By the way, this stage is optional.

Also you can add `$unwind` or `$arrayElemAt index 0` or whatever to get only one value from the array.

Also, to do it in mongoose you only need to replace `"Summer"` with your variable.

Comment: I think it seems to work. One more query, what if user selects one or more category like user wants to filter product whose category are summer and rainy?

Comment: Do you mean [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wTdjkdvOj9x)?

Comment: Yes. Second example would not be efficient if there are lots of records

Comment: Yes, is better to do in one step and avoid iterate over each value in each document. So first example is a good option but maybe syntax is a bit hard to understand

Comment: I have another question in this query. What if user selects one or more category like user wants to filter product whose category are summer or rainy? Then this will not work ryt?